# Endless loop on front end after editing product

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

I'm guessing I won't get far with this question but lets try.

My production magento install is having an issue.  Server load skyrockets after saving a product but it seems to be triggered by the front end.  After the save on the backend, its fine. But try to view it on the front end and the whole system goes down for several minutes.  This only happens once.  After that the system is fine.

Using [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/) I found that the normal 10 queries a second skyrockets to 400+ /sec.  I turned on query logging for a few seconds, and I got 2.5 meg of queries.  It seems to be stuck in an endless loop of the same set of 20 or so queries.

I'm not sure if I broke the loop in the right spot but it repeats these over and over:

```
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address` AS `main_table` WHERE (quote_id = '27211')
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AS `main_table` WHERE (address_id = '87154')
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_billing_agreement` AS `main_table` WHERE (customer_id = '') AND (status = 'active') ORDER BY agreement_id DESC
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_payment` AS `main_table` WHERE (quote_id = '27211')
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (quote_address_id = '87153')
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (quote_address_id = '87154')
350 Query   SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='3185') AND (website_id = 0)
350 Query   SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='1785') AND (website_id = 0)
350 Query   SELECT `sales_flat_quote`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE (`sales_flat_quote`.`entity_id`='27211') AND (store_id IN ('1')) AND (is_active = 1)
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `main_table` WHERE (quote_id = '27211')
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AS `main_table` WHERE (item_id IN(39942, 39944))
350 Query   SELECT DISTINCT ea.attribute_code FROM `salesrule_product_attribute` AS `a`
             INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea` ON ea.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
350 Query   SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`ship_width`, `e`.`ship_height`, `e`.`ship_length`, `e`.`ship_separately`, `e`.`ship_box`, `e`.`free_shipping_discount`, `e`.`free_shipping_discount_value`, `e`.`local_pick_up`, `e`.`local_pick_up_value`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.entity_id IN(3185, 2963, 1785, 3185, 1785))
350 Query   SELECT `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`product_id`, `cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status` WHERE (product_id IN('1785', '2963', '3185')) AND (stock_id=1) AND (website_id=1)
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.*, `default_option_title`.`title` AS `default_title`, `store_option_title`.`title` AS `store_title`, IF(store_option_title.title IS NULL, default_option_title.title, store_option_title.title) AS `title`, `default_option_price`.`price` AS `default_price`, `default_option_price`.`price_type` AS `default_price_type`, `store_option_price`.`price` AS `store_price`, `store_option_price`.`price_type` AS `store_price_type`, IF(store_option_price.price IS NULL, default_option_price.price, store_option_price.price) AS `price`, IF(store_option_price.price_type IS NULL, default_option_price.price_type, store_option_price.price_type) AS `price_type` FROM `catalog_product_option` AS `main_table`
             INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_title` AS `default_option_title` ON default_option_title.option_id = main_table.option_id
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_title` AS `store_option_title` ON store_option_title.option_id = main_table.option_id AND store_option_title.store_id = '1'
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `default_option_price` ON default_option_price.option_id = main_table.option_id AND default_option_price.store_id = 0
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `store_option_price` ON store_option_price.option_id = main_table.option_id AND store_option_price.store_id = '1' WHERE (default_option_title.store_id = 0) AND (product_id IN('1785', '2963', '3185'))
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.*, `default_value_title`.`title` AS `default_title`, `store_value_title`.`title` AS `store_title`, IF(store_value_title.title IS NULL, default_value_title.title, store_value_title.title) AS `title`, `default_value_price`.`price` AS `default_price`, `default_value_price`.`price_type` AS `default_price_type`, `store_value_price`.`price` AS `store_price`, `store_value_price`.`price_type` AS `store_price_type`, IF(store_value_price.price IS NULL, default_value_price.price, store_value_price.price) AS `price`, IF(store_value_price.price_type IS NULL, default_value_price.price_type, store_value_price.price_type) AS `price_type` FROM `catalog_product_option_type_value` AS `main_table`
             INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_title` AS `default_value_title` ON default_value_title.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_title` AS `store_value_title` ON store_value_title.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND store_value_title.store_id = '1'
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` AS `default_value_price` ON default_value_price.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND default_value_price.store_id = 0
             LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` AS `store_value_price` ON store_value_price.option_type_id = main_table.option_type_id AND store_value_price.store_id = '1' WHERE (default_value_title.store_id = 0) AND (option_id IN('6558')) ORDER BY sort_order ASC, title ASC
350 Query   SELECT `core_url_rewrite`.`product_id`, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (store_id = '1') AND (is_system = 1) AND (category_id = 0 OR category_id IS NULL) AND (product_id IN('1785', '2963', '3185')) ORDER BY `category_id` DESC
350 Query   SELECT `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`qty` AS `price_qty`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`.`entity_id` AS `product_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` WHERE (entity_id IN('1785', '2963', '3185')) AND (website_id = 0) ORDER BY `entity_id` ASC, `qty` ASC
350 Query   SELECT `main_table`.*, `cp_table`.`type_id`, `status_table`.`stock_status` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `main_table`
             INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp_table` ON main_table.product_id = cp_table.entity_id
             LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `status_table` ON main_table.product_id=status_table.product_id AND main_table.stock_id=status_table.stock_id AND status_table.website_id='1' WHERE (main_table.stock_id = '1') AND (main_table.product_id IN('1785', '2963', '3185'))
```

Eventually it times out and everything goes back to normal.

Any idea on what it is or next steps for troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Are your indexers all set to automatic when saving this? What happens if you set all indexers but stock to manual and then save a product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic due to inactivity from OP.